# How to convert pngs to html5 video with transparent background?

Tags: video, html5-video

Is it possible to convert a sequence of pngs to a video that is

1. **Cross-platform and Cross-browser** compatible (Safari, Chrome, Firefox; desktops, iOS, android),
2. Preserves the **transparent backgrounds** of the pngs?

The closest I've gotten is outputting to webm/VP9, but that doesn't work on safari :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no single codec that supports transparency on all browsers.  On safari there is an extension to HEVC that supports alpha channels, but it’s non standard, and I’m not sure if ffmpeg has support for it. And it will not work on chrome/Firefox